# Gdiplus Bitmap has no Alpha Channel

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+

I am trying to create a Gdiplus::Bitmap by a BITMAPINFO (shortened code example):

```
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    HDC hdc;
    void* pvBits;

    ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = some_width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = some_height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((((bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth * bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight;

    HBITMAP hBM = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, NULL, 0x0);
    FillMemory(pvBits, bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 255);

    HGDIOBJ oldObj = SelectObject(hDC, hBM);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);

    GdiFlush();

    GdiPlusBitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(&bmi, pvBits);
```

My Problem is that the created Bitmap has no alpha channel (PixelFormat24bppRGB). What am I missing?

Comment: There isn't one, nearest available is `BI_PNG`.

Comment: You set 24 bpp instead of 32 bpp. Also `hdc` is unused uninitialized here (actually it should not be present here at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(someOtherDc);
```

you can see an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/capturing-an-image)

Comment: Just a side note: I was working with 32 bit bitmaps the other day and noticed that some of the older documentation does not mention 32 bits per pixel as an acceptable value. It does seem to work on modern machines though.